# Triple Integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, coordinate-systems

Set up, but do not compute, a triple integral to that gives the volume of the
region in the first octant bounded by the plane $y+z=2$ and the cylinder $x=4-y^2$.
Please use $dz\, dy\, dx$ as the order of integration:

Is this correct?
$$\int_{-2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x}}^{\sqrt{4-x}} \int_0^{2-y}  1dzdydx$$

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. In the future you should type any mathematics using Latex. Your limits of integration look wrong to me. You are in the first octant where everything is positive.

Comment: The equation $\;x=4-y^2\;$ is not a cylinder .

Answer (score 0):

In the first octant $x,y,z$ are positive. 
$$\int_{0}^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x}} \int_0^{2-y}  1dzdydx$$ is correct.

Comment: The limit for $\;x\;$ is wrong: it should be $\;0\le x\le \color{red}4\;$